# Align draggable element to grid that starts at parent's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="block" />
    </div>
</body>
```

The `#board` can be positioned anywhere.

For the example, lets assume that it's `position: relative; left: 3px; top: 7px;` (notice that top & left are not the multiplication of 10), `body` has `margin: 0, padding 0`.

I want to make my `#block` to be snapped to `10px x 10px` grid. But that **grid should start at top-left corner of the parent** (`#board`), **not at top-left corner of the page!**

So it should snap my `#block` to `(3,7), (13, 17), (23, 27), ...` instead of `(0,0), (10, 10), (20, 20)...`.

**How to achieve it?**

When I use:

```
jQuery(value).draggable({
    containment: "#board",
    grid: [10,10],
    snap: "#board"
});
```

It snap to `10px x 10px` grid from top-left corner of the page, not `#board` (and only additionally snap to edges of `#board`, which is not the solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have the right idea.  If you position #block relative to #board and follow Shningamae's advice by setting "snap" to true you'll achieve the desired result.  You can verify the result using jQuery's offset method:

```
$('#block').draggable({
    containment: "#board",
    grid: [10,10],
    snap: true,
    stop: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        console.log("Top: " + offset.top + " Left: " + offset.left);
    }
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/63G8H/

Answer (score 1):

Snap is a boolean value that

> If set to a selector or to true (equivalent to '.ui-draggable'),
> the draggable will snap to the edges of the selected elements when
> near an edge of the element.
>
> Default: false

I think your snap option should be "true".

Also we have another option for the snap:

> **snapMode**
>
> Determines which edges of snap elements the draggable will
> snap to. Ignored if snap is false. Possible values: 'inner', 'outer',
> 'both'
>
> Default: 'both'

Source: [JQuery SDK Draggable](http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/draggable)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was blind about that "snap" option. Unfortunately I can mark only one anserw, and even when you was the first, sillfishes gave more complex one (so I think in future people will find it more useful). +1 for documentation link and fast reply :)

Comment: @PolGraphic doesn't matter. He earned it ;)